# Decoding data from PHP Codeigniter YouTube API data library returns NULL

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, youtube-api

I am trying to use json_decode() from YouTube API data, using CI YouTube libs from Google.
Able to retrieve data from file_get_contents($contents); call, but fail to parse data in json_decode($contents); it returns NULL. Am i missing something in api call?

```
$contents = $this->youtube->getPlaylistFeed(.....); // CI yt libs
$cont1 = file_get_contents($contents, TRUE);  // var_dump($cont1); -- has data
$cont2 = json_decode($cont1);                 // var_dump($cont2); -- return NULL
```

I am retrieving data but i can't decode those JSON data.
How can i get parse data like id, title, desc, thumbnail etc .... 
Thanks for your time ...

Comment: are you sure it returns JSON? what in $contents?

Comment: I been expecting to get JSON data back from that call, but i am confuse overall with the ci youtube libs. If i parse with simplexml_load_string(), i can't use data as document says.

Comment: type echo $cont1 and paste the results. chances are the its not json or your missing something and the api isnt activated.

Comment: try json_decode($cont1,TRUE);